# How to modify width in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make a header in my web site in this form

1/logo and name in left

2/links in middle

3/logos of social media in right

I have this code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
    <a>    
    <img src="house.png" style="width:30px" />
      Les maisons</a>
    </div>
    <div class="mx-auto w-100 order-0">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ACCUEIL</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">• CRÉATION des maisons </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">• ENTRETIEN des maisons </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">• CONTACT</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and this is the result:
[image: and this is the result:]

What I need to do:

1/change width of elemnt in middle so they became inline

2/make the nav in white and modify color of text inside

Comment: Ok. What is your question?

Comment: I need to make elements in middle inline I mean not in two lines

Comment: What is hindering you to do so?

Comment: like you see in my image of result when the text of link is long , the text is divised on 2 lines, I don't know how to have all  the width of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use text-nowrap class for all  elements in your nav
2. remove .navbar-dark in  elements

Answer (score 1):

Change Some Classes in your HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-between">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse dual-collapse2">
    <a>    
    <img src="house.png" style="width:30px" />
      Les maisons</a>
    </div>
    <div class="mx-auto order-0">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">ACCUEIL</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">• CRÉATION des maisons </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">• ENTRETIEN des maisons </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">• CONTACT</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gqxtz1u4/